# how i can set In the sort by options, instead of “Position” please make this say “Best Selling” in magento?

Tags: product-list

hello friend i want to set sort by options, instead of “Position” please make this say “Best Selling” in product page of magento how this is possible ? please guide me

Comment: do you mean on a search results page? have you tried anything currently?

Comment: no in product list page we have option in magento toolbar sort by "position,name and price" so now i want to change position to best selling and i am try this below code  <?php if ($_order=="Position" ) {?>
             <?php $_order ="Best Selling" ?>
            <?php }?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The array containing the options for sorting by are built in the class `Mage_Catalog_Model_Config`

```
public function getAttributeUsedForSortByArray()
{
    $options = array(
        'position'  => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Position')
    );
    foreach ($this->getAttributesUsedForSortBy() as $attribute) {
        /* @var $attribute Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Abstract */
        $options[$attribute->getAttributeCode()] = $attribute->getStoreLabel();
    }

    return $options;
}
```

You could rewrite this class with your own and then override this function and change the text assigned to the 'position' section of the array.

Another option would be to use the `setAvailableOrders` on the class `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar` and change the array at this point.

If it is just the text that you are wanting to change then maybe the second option would be the easiest. You can then get the available orders, change the text in the array and then set them again.

Answer (score 6):

If all you need to do is change some text and not the behaviour then the simplest option is to use translation.

In your theme create a `locale/en_US` folder, or whichever language you are using, and in that create a `translate.csv`.  For example, if it's the theme `default/default` then create `app/design/frontend/default/default/locale/en_US/translate.csv`. Enter the following into it:

```
"Position","Best Selling"
```

Clear the cache after saving and you should see the change.

Comment: This is the least obtrusive method.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on David Manners's answer, here is a low-impact example of how to override the method in a subclass of `Mage_Catalog_Model_Config`:

```
public function getAttributeUsedForSortByArray()
{
    $options = parent::getAttributeUsedForSortByArray();
    $options['position'] = 'My New Label';
    return $options;
}
```

Comment: The OP would like to rename the option not remove it totally I believe.

Comment: That is an excellent point. :-) I will update my answer. (I wanted to simply remove it, so that's what I had written originally, forgetting OP question.)